# Why are Joda objects immutable?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have read that with a Java version less than 7, Joda Time objects are more reliable than Java's built-ins.  One cited reason is that Joda objects are immutable.  Why is this beneficial?  If I want to change the year, hour, and timezone of a Joda DateTime object, I need to make three copies!

Comment: Conversely, if your DateTime objects are not immutable, you are *supposed* to clone it every time you pass it as a parameter to some third party API... given that Java doesn't have `const`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> If I want to change the year, hour, and timezone of a Joda DateTime object, I need to make three copies!

Yes, indeed. Or you could create *one* new object, using all the fields you like from the old object, of course.

This is a thoroughly good thing - because it means when you want to rely on an object not changing, it won't. Consider this pseudo-code:

```
private static final Instant EARLIEST_ALLOWED_ARTICLE = ...;

private Instant creationTimestamp;

public Article(Instant creationTimestamp, ...) {
    if (creationTimestamp.isBefore(EARLIEST_ALLOWED_ARTICLE)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumetnException(...);
    }
    this.creationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;
    ...
}
```

That's fine, because `Instant` is immutable. If it were mutable, the validation in the constructor would be worthless - unless you created a defensive copy at that point.

In my experience, you want to pass around references and know that the values won't change more than you want to actually make changes to existing objects, so immutability leads to fewer bugs (with mutable objects you can *forget* to take a copy, and any validation is then useless) and fewer copies being made.

Basically, it allows you to reason about your code *locally* without making copies of everything you either accept and store, or return to other code. When *only your code* can change the state of your object, it's much simpler to work out what will happen over time.

Joda Time actually fails somewhat because it has both mutable *and* immutable types - if you just program to the *interface* (e.g. `ReadableInstant`) then you don't get those guarantees. That's why in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) I made all the types genuinely immutable.

Out of interest, would you want `String` to be mutable? If not, try to think about whether there are real differences between the two scenarios.

Comment: These are excellent points. But are dates really something special, like the "primitives" (numbers and strings) that are immutable? What you describe brings up the question why we shouldn't make *all* classes mutable and why not *every* setter *ever* is making a copy before changing the value. It does not really make sense to write `clone` or `copy` in every setter that you write. This hints at a fundamental problem, instead.

Comment: @caw: Yes, I would say that dates really *are* something special. It can definitely be convenient to have mutable types, although I *generally* prefer immutable ones where feasible. But if the low-level "primitive" types were all mutable, then that *choice* of mutability or immutability would be much harder to implement... immutable classes would have to clone everything *all the time*. Urgh.

Comment: Thanks! I don't really see the major difference yet between dates and other common objects (e.g. Collections, `Calendar`, objects from business logic). Anyway, there's a *substantial* difference between objects that are not *meant* to be changed later (and thus may not have any public setters, anyway), where you just need to clone the data that you receive in your constructors/setters (as in your `Article` example above, which is also what Joshua Bloch recommends in "Effective Java"), and objects which *are* meant to change, which then need to copy themself in every setter.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is that once you create an object, you know that it *cannot* change. This means that you won't run into a situation where your data changes in unexpected ways (in other parts of the code or different threads, perhaps).

This makes the object's behaviour more predictable and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

There might be many reasons but one good one regards hashing.  Immutable objects can be used in hashing data structures (e.g. HashSet, keys in HashMaps, etc) because their hash code and "equality" semantics will not change.  Mutable objects are not suitable for hashing since mutations might change their hash code or equality.

By making Joda dates immutable they can now be used in hashing data structures.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that it's due to this:

Imagine you have a java.util.Date-object, that is used in multiple classes. I'm doing development on one class, you on the other. Then, I decide that I need to predict the future, but instead of creating a new Date-object, I take the one that I already have, the one you think represent a certain point in time, and I add three hours to it. Now, your code might run into serious problems at runtime. This can all be avoided using an immutable object, because you can't change its state, you can't mess it up for anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the implementation of DateTime is not immutable[1], since no `final` is used.

https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/DateTime.java

[1] the term "immutable" is commonly understood to mean "thread-safe immutable".

Comment: I don't understand.. DateTime is a `final` class, and if you mean fields in `BaseDateTime` then yes those aren't `final` and can be modified using reflection but in that way `String` is also not immutable.