# Compare time using JodaTime in Android

Tags: java, android, jodatime, android-jodatime

I need to compare whether a DateTime object is greater/less than 9AM PST using JodaTime library in Android.
I am getting the DateTime object in PST like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" ));
```

How can I compare whether the time recorded for this object is greater/less than 9AM PST?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the next ways to do what you want.

1) Create a `DateTime` with the `TimeZone` and the hour that you want.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime()
             .withHourOfDay(9)
             .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

And then compare `dt` with the `DateTime` that you receive, create, etc.

`dt.isAfter(date)` or `dt.isBefore(date)`

2) You can set the `TimeZone` that you want to a copy of the `DateTime` that you receive.

I say copy because `DateTime` object is immutable. You can not modify the DateTime which you receive but create one from it, yes. You can read more about that here: [Why are Joda objects immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518654/why-are-joda-objects-immutable)

```
datePST = date.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles"));
int hour = datePST.getHourOfDay()
```

Now you just need to check if hour is < or > than 9.